# Check if object exists in multi-level list at specified path

Tags: r, r-package

I have a multi-level list `l` with an arbitrary number of levels and entries. To give a simple example:

```
l <- list(a = 1,
          b = list(x = 2, y = 3),
          c = list(dog = 5, cat = list(fish = 3, mouse = 10))
         )
```

In my package, the user passes an "address" which specifies an object in this list. The address is passed as a string, of the form:

```
address = "$c$cat$fish"
```

This excludes the name of the list itself.

I have written a function which checks whether the address is "valid", in the sense that I want to check whether an object exists at the specified address. The main substance of the function is as follows:

```
# this is the call to evaluate, as a string
expr_str <- paste0("address_value <- l", address)

# evaluate the call
eval(str2lang(expr_str))

if(is.null(address_value)){
   warning("Address is NULL or not found in list")
}
```

Now, this works (although there is probably a more elegant way to do it). But the problem is that I get a NOTE in the CMD check because the `address_value` doesn't have a visible binding, because it is created inside `eval()`.

I want to get rid of the note but I'm not sure how to retrieve whatever is (or isn't) at `address` without using `eval()`.

Can anyone help with this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assignment to `address_value` can be *outside* of the `eval`, which avoids the undeclared variable nag in the CMD check.

```r
check_address <- function(address) {
  
  expr_str <- paste0("l", address)
  
  # evaluate the call
  address_value <- eval(str2lang(expr_str))
  
  if(is.null(address_value)){
    warning("Address is NULL or not found in list")
  }
  
  address_value
}
```

Which results in:

```r
check_address("$c$cat$fish")
#> [1] 3

check_address("$c$cat$banana")
#> NULL
#> Warning message:
#> In check_address("$c$cat$banana") : Address is NULL or not found in list
```

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Have you considered using `purrr::pluck`? I think it matches your requirements:

```r
l %>% pluck('c', 'cat', 'fish')
```

```
[1] 3
```

Comment: This could probably work but I would have to re-write other functions to fit this syntax. I'm also trying to avoid depending on other packages as much as possible. But thanks for the suggestion!